# Add Product Description on Simple Product Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-list, product-listing

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to add a description to a Simple Product that will subsequently be displayed on the Simple Product Details Page. Everywhere I have looked discusses using code to handle this but like i said in my last post im new to magento and cannot figure out how to solve this issue with code solutions provided as they seem to gear towards more advanced developers.

Comment: Have you added description on product in admin panel?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir No that's what im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add product description in simple product only, you can follow below steps.

1) Create a `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` and paste below code in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.description.simple" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/type/simple/description.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2) Create a `description.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/simple/description.phtml` and paste below code.

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('description')->getStoreLabel();
$_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description')) ? $_product->getAttributeText('description') : '';
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
    <div class="product-description">
        <strong class="type"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeLabel ?></strong>
        <div class="value"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

3) Flush magento cache and check simple product in which you have added description in backend.

Comment: Where do i add the product descriptions?

Comment: You can add product description here: `Admin > Catalog > Products > Add New  or Edit Product > Content > Description`. In default magento, it is not required to code separately to show description. By default it will be display if you have added in backend.

Comment: Welcome and enjoy :)